# Windows Xp - writing cache - dialog freezed

Tags: windows-xp

Within a Windows Xp SP3 VM (via VMWare), the writing cache dialog is disabled. 
It is able to invoke the dialog but the settings in the gui controls cannot be modified.
Has anbody already experienced such an issue?

EDIT: The admin role is assigned towards my user. Pic upload.
[image]

Comment: A screenshot of the problem might be of some assistance.

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess.  You are on a domain and are NOT an `Administrator` on it.  The dialog isn't frozen its just locked because of your permission.

Comment: nope concerning your second assumption

Comment: So you are not on a domain?  Why did you mention you were a local `Administrator` then?

Comment: to avoid an usual hint like 'you are not an admin'.